Wrong material icon "Delete" is being imported in androd project
I tried to import the Delete icon from the material icons in my android project but what I am actually getting is very different from the one displayed on the website.
Here is the side by side comparison:




Displayed on the website
Actually displayed in the Compose Preivew in Android Studio










This is the suggestion from Android Studio when I am trying to use the Delete icon:

From the screenshot you can see that the actual rendered icon looks like the DeleteOutline icon from the suggestion.

I am using the composeBOM and the material-icons.extended-android library
val composeBomVersion = "2023.10.01"
implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:$composeBomVersion"))
implementation("androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended-android")

The import statement and usage is:
import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.outlined.Delete

val Delete = Icons.Outlined.Delete

 Icon(
     imageVector = Delete,
     contentDescription = "Delete Alarm"
 )

Could you tell me if I am doing it the wrong way or there could be something wrong with the Android Studio or with the library itself.

Try removing the androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended-android or trying invalidate cache and restart android studio

I am using lots of icons from the androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended-android library, so removing it will break many files and then the gradle will not build and hence no preview. Although I tried invalidating the cache but it didn't work.
